# Don't allow insert triggers to execute simultaneously

Tags: sql-server, triggers

Below is a a trigger for an SQL insert statement. The table contains project records. Within the trigger is a call to a stored proc that will generate a project number by looking at the last project number created then incrementing it then returning the project number in the output parameter. This project number is then assigned to the newly created project record. Project Number is supposed to be unique although this is not a constraint on the table.

The problem i'm having is that it appears the trigger is being executed at the same time when multiple projects are being created at the same time in our application. This is causing the same project number being generated and being assigned to the new project record. These duplicate project numbers are causing issues.

I am trying to figure out how to prevent this from happening. Ideally I would like for the insert trigger not to be able to be executed at the same time by multiple transactions but rather queue up and wait for an executing trigger to complete before executing the next one.

```
   DECLARE @Id INT
   DECLARE @isUnique bit = 0
   DECLARE @projectNumber VARCHAR(50)

    SELECT @Id = ins.Id FROM INSERTED ins;
        
    WHILE @isUnique = 0
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO #tmp EXEC spCalculateProjectNumber @projectNumber OUTPUT
        IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM project WHERE projectnumber = @projectNumber)
        BEGIN
                UPDATE project SET projectnumber = @projectNumber WHERE id = @id
                SET @isUnique = 1
        END
    END
```

Comment: Required reading: [Brent Ozar: The Silent Bug I Find in Most Triggers](https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2019/05/the-silent-bug-i-find-in-most-triggers/) you are not handling multiple rows in the `inserted` table (for that matter you don't handle *no* rows either, nor do you handle the `deleted` table for an `update` trigger if this is one). What does `spCalculateProjectNumber` do? Perhaps we can make that set-based also

Comment: You need to have a **reliably unique** source for your project numbers - for SQL Server, the best choices are an `INT IDENTITY` column on the table itself, or a `SEQUENCE` object in SQL Server which you can ask for the "next available number" - realiably, and concurrently.  Most "roll-your-own" approaches have serious flaws in that they can't handle "concurrent" requests - as seems to be the case here. Don't reinvent the wheel and waste a lot of time on that - use the existing features!

Comment: To reinforce other comments: don't use a trigger for this, use an `identity`. Many people have taken your approach then realised after much pain that they just should have used an identity.

Comment: Yeah your use of triggers is in conflict with every good practice advice - triggers need to be - if they are truly essential - concise and do as little as possible. You are assuming it will only ever fire for a single row - triggers operate on a set, so if more than one row is inserted in the same batch, what will @Id be? And using a trigger to calcuate the next in a sequence is a rusty wheel compared to the built-in `identity/sequence` methods.